# Reusing Mock to create attribute mocks unittest.patch

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking, python-unittest

```
from unittest.mock import patch


class A:
    def b(self):
        return 'HAHAHA A'
a = A()

with patch('__main__.A') as a_mock:
    a_mock.b.return_value = 'not working'
    print(a.b())

HAHAHA A
>>>
```

Why doesn't it print `'not working'`? What for is a_mock, then? ______________

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You replaced the *whole class* with your patch, not the method on the existing class. `a = A()` created an instance of `A` before you replaced the class, so `a.__class__` still references the actual class, not the mock.

Mocking can only ever replace one reference at a time, and not the object referenced. Before the patch, both the names `A` and the attribute `a.__class__` are references to the class object. You then patched only the `A` reference, leaving `a.__class__` in place.

In other words, `a.__class__` is not patched, only `A`, and `A().b()` *would* print `not working`.

You'd have to patch *just* the method on the class, so that `a.__class__` still references `A`, and  `a.b` will resolve to the patched `A.b` mock:

```
with patch('__main__.A.b') as b_mock:
    b_mock.return_value = 'working as long as you patch the right object'
    print(a.b())
```

Demo:

```
>>> with patch('__main__.A.b') as b_mock:
...     b_mock.return_value = 'working as long as you patch the right object'
...     print(a.b())
...
working as long as you patch the right object
```

You can't, unfortunately, patch the `a.__class__` reference with a `Mock`; Python only lets you use actual classes for that attribute.

```
>>> with patch('__main__.a.__class__') as a_class_mock:
...     a_class_mock.b.return_value = 'working as long as you patch the right object'
...     print(a.b())
...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/mjpieters/Development/Library/buildout.python/parts/opt/lib/python3.5/unittest/mock.py", line 1312, in __enter__
    setattr(self.target, self.attribute, new_attr)
TypeError: __class__ must be set to a class, not 'MagicMock' object
```

Comment: so changing a class attribute changes `__class__` on all instances of the class, whereas changing class does not? So if I want to monkey-patch the class just to be sure nothing bad gets executed and then patch some methods I can do:
`with patch('__main__.A'):
     with patch('__main__.A.b', return_value = 'working'):
         print(a.b())
`    ?

Comment: @Adam: `a` is an instance of `A`. You can later replace `A`, but the instance will still reference the class, it won't be updated to use the mock.

Comment: @Adam: and `a.b` resolves to `A.b` because Python attribute lookup on instances will 'fall back' to the class if an attribute isn't defined on the instance itself; `a.b` looks through `a.__dict__`, then `a.__class__.__dict__`, and then on through all of `a.__class__.__mro__` to scan the full class hierarchy.

Comment: @Adam: if you leave `A` in place (unpatched), then `a.__class__.b` will use the `A.b` reference, which you *can* replace.

Comment: And when I patch `A` first, how come the `with patch('__main__.A.b', return_value = 'working')` won't change the `__class__` on `a` like it does when it is not nested in `with patch('__main__.A'):` ?

Comment: @Adam: you are only changing the `A.b` reference. `a.__class__` still points to `A`, which in turn references the mock. It is that 2-step reference chain that lets you replace just the method.

Comment: @Adam: for each `.` attribute reference in a series, Python looks up the next attribute on the previously resolved object. `a` is found as a global, then `type(a).__getattribute__(a, 'b')` is executed to handle the attribute lookup, which in turn looks for `'b'` first in `a.__dict__`, doesn't find it there, then looks through all the objects in `type(a).__mro__` (== `a.__class__.__mro__`) to see if any class in that series has the attribute `'b'` and retrieves that. Because you have another reference to `a.__class__`, namely `__main__.A`, you can swap out `'b'` still and have `a.b` find that.

Comment: So when I do:
`with patch('__main__.A'):
    with patch('__main__.A.b', return_value='not working'):
        print(a.b())`
, the global name `A` would be referencing the `a_mock` and the second `b` patch just changes the `a_mock.b` not the original `A.b` (`A` to which `a` is pointing). So that's actually the same behavior like I have in the question.

Comment: @Adam: yes, the first patch changed the `__main__.A` reference, so the second patch will patch `b` on the mock.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to patch your instance instead of your class:

```
with patch('__main__.a') as a_mock:
    a_mock.b.return_value = 'works perfectly ;)'
    print(a.b())
```